# Removing knockouts in composite granite sink

Tags: plumbing, tools, installation, sink

The sink has one existing hole, and 3 knockouts which are cut about half way through the material.

What are the best tools, and techniques for removing fixture knockouts on a composite granite sink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As brutal as it seems, the prescribed method by FRANKE is to use a blunt ended large punch and a hammer.  Set the punch dead center in the cutout and strike it soundly. Don't be too tentative, give it a good shot! Place the punch on the top. If you have a carbide hole saw, pilot a small hole dead center from the side already drilled then finish it off from the top, using the pilot hole.

When I first saw my plumber do this on a kitchen job, I cringed, but it worked well. Weren't there any instructions with your sink?  I'm just relating the way FRANKE recommends, maybe your brand has a different method.

Comment: So no use for a carbide hole saw?  After forking over that kind of cash, I'm tentative to smash it with a hammer.

Comment: Do you place the punch on the top (where the sticker indicating there is a "hole" there), or the bottom (where the partial cutout is visible)?

Comment: the instructions say on the top.  .  If you already have the saw, then pilot a small hole dead center from the side already  drilled then finish it off from the top, using the pilot hole.